# How can I read uploaded CSV file data and create nodes from it?

Tags: 7, files

I have created custom module. but don't know how to read uploaded file data and add into perticular content type. HTML File upload is displayed but after upload file unable to read content.

```
 function custom_add_node_data_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['custom_add_node_data/add_data'] = array(
        'title'             =>  '',  //page title
        'description'       =>  '',  //description show when mouse hover on link
        'page callback'     =>  'upload_file_form',  //callback function which is invoked when menu item is called.
        'access callback'   =>  true,  //any user can access this page
       );
     return $items;
}
```

Below are the callback functions:

```
function upload_file_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form=array();

   $form['upload'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#name' => 'custom_content_csv_file',
    );

    $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Upload'),
    );

   return $form;   

}

function upload_file_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 $file = file_save_upload('upload', array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('txt'),
    ));

    //get the content in the file
    $content = file_get_contents($file->uri);
var_dump($content);
    //remove the file in temp and the pointer in the database
    file_delete($file);

    //remove the file in temp and the pointer in the database
    //file_delete($file);
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do this in a custom module? There are contributed modules that can handle this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there's already an [example module](https://github.com/xurizaemon/csvimport/tree/7.x-1.x) on GitHub that explains it really well and the question otherwise is too broad.

Comment: why you are not using https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds?